# using clEnqueueNativeKernel in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

Is there any example of using clEnqueueNativeKernel in OpenCL? In this way one can write a kernel in a c or c++ language. Do other commands remain unchanged?

Comment: Could you specify the goal you want to achieve. Question is too general right now.

Comment: I wanted to write a native c++ kernel. Therefore I should use clEnqueueNativeKernel command. I was looking for a source to read about the merit and demerit of Native Kernels and also the way that one can use them. It seems they are not supported on all platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native C++ "kernels" are essentially just functions that you want to execute within command queue to preserve order of commands.

AFAIK they are not supported on GPU. If you want to execute C++ functions across all devices, you should consider to use cl_event callbacks (when status == CL_COMPLETE).

Assume you have a buffer object you want to read from device and pass to your C++ function. Also you want to pass some integer value as well
(I use C++ OpenCL wrapper):

```
// First of all, we should define a struct which describes our arguments list.
struct Arguments
{
    int integer;
    void* buffer_host;
};

// Define C/C++ function you want to call.
void CFunction(void *args)
{
    Arguments args = reinterpret_cast<Arguments*>(args);
    // Do something with args->integer and args->buffer_host.
}

// ...
Arguments args = {.integer = 0, .buffer_host = NULL};

// First, we should define Buffer objects in arguments.
std::vector<cl::Memory> buffers_dev;
buffers_dev.push_back(a_buffer);

// Then we should define pointers to *pointer in args* which will be set
// when OpenCL read data from buffers_dev to the host memory.
std::vector<const void*> buffers_host;
buffers_host.push_back(&args.buffer_host);

// Finally, set integer
args.integer = 10;

queue.enqueueNativeKernel(CFunction,
                          std::make_pair(&args, siezof(Arguments)),
                          &buffers_dev,
                          &buffers_host);

// At this point args were copied by OpenCL and you may reuse or delete it.
```